# Moving the cursor to another textbox after Enter Event - VBA

Tags: vba

Could you please help me?

With the code below, I can "Setfocus" and change the "Backcolor" of "Me.txtFT".

But, when I am trying to move the cursor to "Me.txtFT" after an "Enter" event on "txtPT", the cursor is not moving, it keeps on the "txtPT".

I am using the code below.

```
Private Sub txtPT_Enter()
    If Trim(Me.txtPT.Value & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox """FT field"" must contain a value before continue. Please try again": _
        Me.txtFT.SetFocus: _
        Me.txtFT.BackColor = &H80FFFF: _
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: `Me.txtFT.SetFocus()` - why have you got `: _` ?

Comment: These `: _` instruction separator / line continuation tokens are turning what should be 3 separate logical lines of code into 1 logical line spanning 3 physical ones. Do that for 20 lines and your code stops compiling. Worse, it makes debugging a complete nightmare, because breakpoints are set on *logical* lines of code, so setting a breakpoint on either line red-highlights the whole entire chunk. Consider dropping that habit. End-of-line is a perfectly fine end-of-instruction token, you're fighting the language here.

Comment: How do you move the cursor? Arrow keys? Mouse? Tab or Enter? Is there any other event procedure attached to txtPT? Is there any event procedure attached to txtFT?

Comment: Is the under Enter Event on "Me.txtPT", I would like the cursor goes to "Me.txtFT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is testing the length of `txtPT` but the message is warning about `txtFT`, so it's unclear from the code what the intent might be.

Instead of handling the *entry* into control B to validate the value of control A, consider handling the *exit* from control A - and cancel it losing the focus with an invalid value in the first place:

```
Private Sub txtFT_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    With txtFT
        If Len(Trim(.Text & vbNullString)) = 0 Then
            Cancel.Value = True
            .BackColor = &H80FFFF
            MsgBox "[FT] cannot be empty!"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My idea is if the user try to select the "me.txtPT" before insert an amount in "me.txtFT", the user get a message and the cursor goes to the "me.txtFT".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Mathieu Guindon

Comment: @AndreVioti what about the message not making sense for the condition being checked? Field1 is empty, message is about Field2. The better UX (and simpler implementation) is to validate the value of the field you're in *before* it loses focus, and then to *prevent* exiting the control given an invalid value.

Comment: Do you havê any suggestion?

Comment: @AndreVioti I don't understand, did not you read my answer and test if it works for you? Note that the condition is different (you're testing whether the value is 0, here this is testing whether the *length* of the text is 0; you're also testing the value of the wrong field if the msgbox message is to be believed) - that's very likely why your code isn't working (try entering a literal `0` in `txtPT`), but I strongly recommend flipping your `Enter` approach to handle `Exit` instead.

Comment: @ Mathieu Guindon, I have changed as your suggestion, and now I think it makes more sense. I am learning a lot with all the outcomes from here..Thanks a lot and apologies for any mess